# How to make a script work for specific form on a page with mulitple forms

Tags: forms

I am using a script that disables the submit button unless the user clicks and browses for a file to upload.

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                    $('input:file').change(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).val()){
                                $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                            }
                            else {
                                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
                            }
                        });
                });
```

I have 2 forms on the same page and I would like this tied to a specific form.

First form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="name1" id="id1">
```

Second form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="name2" id="id2">
```

is there a way in the javascript to attach it to #id1 specifically and not id2?

would I place it like this?   `$('#id1.input:submit')` - what is the symbol or syntax to add the id into the script?  Sorry I'm still learning which parts you can combine.

Comment: I not understand all of your question, why don't use $('form#id1')

Comment: That's where I'm going with it but I couldn't figure out which part of the code the #id1 goes in.  Does that replace the $(document) part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `$('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);` by
`$('form#id1 input:submit').attr('disabled',true);`

Comment: wow.. I didn't know a space was allowed there.  That is awesome to know.  Thank you Pitsanu.  Much appreciated!  What is this part called so I can read up on it more?  $(this part here).attr